# Howto debug the "something went wrong" error with javascript/ajax calls

Tags: javascript, debugging

i have some scripts which give me the alert "Something went wrong". I tried firebug, i tried logging everything (i'm on a django environement) but there's no trace of any error message. So, instead of posting the code (which actually works, just sometimes doesn't...), i'd like to ask what's the better way to debug that error, or if there's any tool similar to firebug that can help.

Apparently, searching on google, doesn't help this time. Also: where does that error come from? Where can i find more info about? I think it's somehow related to the browser (i'm on Firefox, but i get the same error on Chrome) but i'm not sure.

Thanks all in advance and i hope this post isn't off-topic

S.

Comment: "which actually works, just sometimes doesn't" ... that would be an excellent reason to **post the code**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the 'Network' panel in Google Chrome or the 'Net' panel in Firebug. You can see all XHTTPRequests there and see the requests and responses, the response probably contains a 500 status code and a description.